# How to capture form's fields focus lost event in prototypejs

Tags: javascript, forms, event-handling, prototypejs

I have a simple form like this:

```
<form id='myForm'>

    <input type='text' name='Textbox'>

    <select name='SelectBox'>
     <option class='option1'>option 1</option>
     <option class='option2'>option 2</option>
   </select>

</form>
```

I want to capture this form's Textbox focus lost (blur) event and SelectBox change event.

I don't want to apply change event for whole form because it causing to submit form more than one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `id='SelectBox'` to your select box and `id='Textbox'` to your text box and try the following:

```
function handleTextBoxBlur(event, element) {
  console.log("blur");
  console.log(element);
}
function handleSelectBoxChange(event, element) {
  console.log("change");
  console.log(element);
}

document.observe("dom:loaded", function(event) {

  $("Textbox").on("blur", "input", handleTextBoxBlur);
  $("SelectBox").on("change", "select", handleSelectBoxChange);

});
```

Comment: The key part here being the adding of the event listeners to your particular select element. Here are the prototype docs: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/

Answer (score 0):

> $('input').focus_lost(function() {
>   /*write what Ever code need*/
>   });
>
> $('option').change(function() {
>    /*write what Ever code need*/
>   });
>
> /*This is suitable only for this given form..Learn more from [a link](http://api.jquery.com/)  >and http://jqueryui.com/*/