# Event.observe field active? (prototype.js)

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

Is it possible to observe an input field and only do an action when a field is no longer the active field? (i.e. when the user clicks on another input field?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for the 'blur' event. Here's a similar question/answer: [How to capture form's fields focus lost event in prototypejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902042/how-to-captute-forms-fields-focus-lost-event-in-prototypejs/7905052#7905052)